# How to make the tableview cell that has been selected to no color as Vine App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

**How to make the tableview cell that has been selected to no color as Vine App.**

I've tried it but with clear color but the cell white out when it is get selected

Vine example no background color change
https://vid.me/tfkk

My project : Cell color changed even if it was set to clearColor
https://vid.me/awCq

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DiscvoerTVC

    let colorView = UIView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = nil
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.DiscoverViewColor.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.DiscoverViewLabel.text = "USMLE CK"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let colorView = UIView()
        colorView.backgroundColor = nil
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean cell's selection style? If so, set its selection style to none

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None;
```